# :nth-child doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is the html of a wordpress plugin for ajax loading posts

```
<div class="row newsrow">
  <div>
    <div id="ajax-load-more" class="ajax-load-more-wrap alm-0" data-alm-id="0" data-canonical-url="http://bayron.nl/" data-slug="home">
      <ul class="alm-listing alm-ajax  " data-repeater="default" data-post-type="post" data-post-format="" data-category="" data-category-not-in="" data-tag="" data-tag-not-in="" data-taxonomy="" data-taxonomy-terms="" data-taxonomy-operator="" data-taxonomy-relation=""
        data-meta-key="" data-meta-value="" data-meta-compare="" data-meta-relation="" data-meta-type="" data-year="" data-month="" data-day="" data-author="" data-post-in="" data-post-not-in="" data-exclude="" data-search="" data-custom-args="" data-post-status=""
        data-order="DESC" data-orderby="date" data-offset="0" data-posts-per-page="3" data-lang="" data-scroll="false" data-scroll-distance="150" data-max-pages="0" data-pause-override="false" data-pause="false" data-button-label="Older Posts" data-button-class=""
        data-destroy-after="" data-transition="fade" data-images-loaded="true">
        <div class="alm-reveal">
          <li>
            <div class="list-content">
              <img width="360" height="240" src="http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/helsinki.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/helsinki.jpg 360w, http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/helsinki-300x200.jpg 300w"
                sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px">
              <h3><a href="http://bayron.nl/2017/01/27/future-digital-finance-forum/" title="FUTURE DIGITAL FINANCE FORUM">FUTURE DIGITAL FINANCE FORUM</a></h3>
              <p>April 2017 | Helsinki | Keynote Speaker</p>
              <p>Future Digital Finance Forum gathers the pioneers and decision makers to discuss the opportunities and challenges caused by digitalization and disruption in the industry.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list-content">
              <img width="384" height="240" src="http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/wroclaw.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/wroclaw.jpg 384w, http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/wroclaw-300x188.jpg 300w"
                sizes="(max-width: 384px) 100vw, 384px">
              <h3><a href="http://bayron.nl/2017/01/27/impactcee-2016-fintechinsurtech/" title="IMPACTCEE 2016  FINTECH/INSURTECH">IMPACTCEE 2016  FINTECH/INSURTECH</a></h3>
              <p>December 2016 | Wroclaw | Keynote Speaker</p>
              <p>This is the most content driven fintech congress in the Central Eastern Europe gathering the top industry innovators.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list-content">
              <img width="360" height="191" src="http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/classof17.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/classof17.jpg 360w, http://bayron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/classof17-300x159.jpg 300w"
                sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px">
              <h3><a href="http://bayron.nl/2017/01/27/meet-the-11-startup-teams-from-our-fintech-cybersecurity-2017-class/" title="MEET THE 11 STARTUP TEAMS FROM OUR FINTECH &amp; CYBERSECURITY 2017 CLASS!">MEET THE 11 STARTUP TEAMS FROM OUR FINTECH &amp; CYBERSECURITY 2017 CLASS!</a></h3>
              <p>November 2016 | Startup Bootcamp</p>
              <p>On the 22-23 of November, Selection Days for our FinTech &amp; CyberSecurity program took place. The event was very special: not only it was selecting the first cohort for our recently announced FinTech &amp; CyberSecurity program but also
                celebrating the 100th startup selected for the programs in Amsterdam.<br> The event truly was a celebration of entrepreneurship, empowerment, ecosystem and innovation. <a href="https://youtu.be/uPsCgRjL6bc" target="_blank">Watch the aftermovie to feel the energy.</a></p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
      <div class="alm-btn-wrap"><button id="load-more" class="alm-load-more-btn more">Older Posts</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's a lot but I want to show it because I don't exactly know where the problem is. I'll try to explain where the classes that I use are in the HTML

These are the only 2 nth-child 's I use in the project and they don't work.

```
.alm-listing > li:nth-child(4) {
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 5%
}

.alm-listing > li:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff
}
```

The class of .alm-listing starts in the 4th HTML element; the unordered list
then the css should select the list elements in that UL. And in those list elements the 3rd and 4th element (two different paragraphs) should be getting selected by the nth-childs. Don't worry about the div with class of list-contents, I've tried taking it out but the css still won't work.

If there is anyone out there that can help me I would appreciate it so much!

Comment: The > means direct child element which the li aren't, there is a div .alm-reveal in between. Have you tried removing that div? Or change the CSS to .alm-listing > div > li:nth-child() ?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. I've even tried changing .alm-listing to .alm-reveal in the css but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is you are trying to style `<li>` directly inside of the `<ul>` as that's that the `alm-listing > li` does, but you have the `<li>` tags inside of another div.

[image: improper nesting]

Try this

```
.alm-listing > div > li:nth-child(4) {
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 5%
}

.alm-listing > div > li:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. If you check www.bayron.nl you can see on of the list elements is at the top of the page, because of the position: absolute. Check the css of the list item that is in the header, it uses the :nth-child(3) code on itself.....WUT?!

Comment: The site looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

Right so I think I found the problem. It's not the CSS. I unminified my CSS so that I could arange some media queries easier. After the unminify is when the problem started. I found a backup of my CSS (minified) from 2 days ago. When I upload the minified version to my site the nth-childs work like they should. I unminified the minified backup and uploaded that to my site, and voila, my code stopped working... I can't beleive this is even a thing. For someone wondering what sites I used to unminify, here they are; unminify.com and codepen.com 's editor (tidy CSS).

Welp I guess I have to start over again ;/

Comment: Good time to start using source control, like git.